# How to run main.dart program after importing firebase_Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Before adding firebase_auth I was able to debug and launch emulator. After  adding firebase_auth to my pubspec.yml and launch I couldn't instead I encountered error

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_auth:classpath'.

> Could not download builder-8.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:8.1.2)

```
  > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/8.1.2/builder-8.1.2.jar'.

     > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/8.1.2/builder-8.1.2.jar'.

        > dl.google.com
```

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s

Comment: can you provide `android -> build.gradle` code?

Comment: The mentioned URL is fine for me, I can download builder-8.1.2.jar. Are you behind some firewall that prevents connection to dl.google.com?